# What is the size when folded of the ORI M9 or Mezzo D9?

Tags: folding-bicycle

ORI M9 and Mezzo D9 seem to have the same frame design. Does anyone know the dimension of these bikes when folded?

Comment: I don't have exact dimensions, but if you look at the image for the ORI  here (http://www.oribikes.com/ori/products/detial.php?M=0&cID=1&Key=3), you can see a picture of it folded.  It uses 16 inch rims, so you can probably estimate the size based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/bikes/folding/product/review-mezzo-bikes-d9-10551) states the following.

> While the D9 doesn't fold quite as small as a Brompton (690x685x360mm to the Brompton's 550x580x280mm)

So the Mezzo D9 folds down to 690 x 685 x 360 mm. Which equates to 27.17 x 26.97 x 14.17 inches.